# zend soap server authorization

Tags: authentication, zend-framework, soap

I have set up a Zend SOAP client and server:

See partial code below. In the client I set a username and password in the headers.

But I cannot find any information on how to extract this in the server so that I can authenticate the incoming message, ideally through the Zend_Auth stuff I already use for the rest of  the system

```
Cient:

$username = "user";
$password = "pass";

// initialize SOAP client
$options = array(
        'location' => 'http://dev.local/api/soap/index',
        'uri'      => 'http://dev.local/api/soap/index',
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
        'login' => $username, 
        'password' => $password
);

try {
    $client = new Zend_Soap_Client(null, $options);


Server:

        $options = array('uri' => 'http://dev.local/api/soap');
        $server = new Zend\Soap\Server(null, $options);
        $manager = new Manager_Api_Soap();
        $server->setClass($manager);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're able to get header values of variables like this within zend:

```
$this->getRequest()->getHeader('login')
```

For further details have a look at a prior answer from me regarding Zend and REST:

[Zend Framework 1.12 plugin for checking "Authorization" header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062339/zend-framework-1-12-plugin-for-checking-authorization-header/18074051#18074051)